# Julia: Add missing value to array

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an array that can take `Float64` and `Missing` values:

`local x::Array{Union{Float64, Missing}, 1} = [1.0, missing, 3.0]`

I can add more `Float64` values using the `append!` function, but I can't add a `missing` value this way. I get the following error:

```
julia> append!(x, missing)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Missing)
```

What's the correct way to add `missing` values to this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have been using `push!` - `append!` is for adding collections, while `push!` is for single values.

Comment: And for the reason why `append!` can be used on numbers: numbers are sometimes treated as 0-dimensional collections and implemented a lot of array-like functions including `size`, `ndims`, `length`, `getindex`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are right that `push!` should be used.
Additionally your code does not need to be so verbose:

```
julia> x = [1.0, missing, 3.0]
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
 1.0
  missing
 3.0

julia> y = Union{Missing, Float64}[]
0-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}

julia> push!(y,1);

julia> push!(y,missing)
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
 1.0
  missing
```

Moreover, instead of `Array{Union{Float64, Missing}, 1}` the shorter and more readable version `Vector{Union{Float64, Missing}}` can be used.